# How can I write to a Shared Resource of Custom Values in TeamCity?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

TeamCity has a feature which is called "[Shared Resources](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/05/explaining-the-shared-resources-plugin/)".  This allows you to configure a set of custom values (i.e., URLs) which can be read from by the locking builds in order to properly share data and avoid resource conflicts.  However, in my situation, the custom values (i.e., environment names) are not known yet.  There is a separate build which will be able to create the environments.  How can I have this build "write" into the custom values of the TeamCity Shared Resources so that the dependent builds can retrieve the most up-to-date values?

Answer (score 0):

Currently parameters are not supported in TeamCity. Here is the related request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-39174 you can vote for.